# Cointegration between a variable of significant seasonality and one with no significant seasonality

Tags: seasonality, cointegration, unit-root

After running programs of deseasonalization, I had an output in which one variable held significant seasonality, for which I corrected, and another that did not have. My main objective was to comprehend a relationship between those variables.

Both variables were tested to be unit root process and then I went for the Johansen test to test the number cointegration vectors, for which I got that I could reject the null of only one.

What should be the intuition here? Suppose I had a large number of observations and so I would not have the usual problems of unit root testing with small samples and all the other tests were correctly specified. Is there something that the literature says about this? A seasonal variable might have a strong and intuitive relationship with a non-seasonal one?

Edit: So a result like the one below would be contradictory if I previously considered both variables as I(1)?

```
Trend: constant                                         Number of obs =      102
Sample:  3 - 104                                                  Lags =       2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                         5%
maximum                                      trace    critical
  rank    parms       LL       eigenvalue  statistic    value
    0      6      -1064.8773           .     29.3877    15.41
    1      9      -1054.6653     0.29682      8.9637     3.76
    2      10     -1050.1834     0.14320
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you have done the following:

1. You remove the seasonality for one of the variables, while no seasonality is found for the other variable (hence, nothing is removed there). Thus now you have two variables that are non-seasonal.
2. You proceed to unit root testing. You find unit roots for both variables.
3. You go for cointegration testing. You reject the null of one cointegrating vector in favour of more than one cointegrating vector. That means there is more than one stationary combination of the two variables, which implies they are both stationary. 
    (Of course, the vectors are normalized; otherwise you could have infinitely many versions of the same cointegrating vector just by scaling it.)

At this point you face a contradiction between the unit root tests and the cointegration test. This should not happen under ideal circumstances. If this happens, you should look for issues like structural changes, conditional heteroskedasticity etc. that invalidate the results of either the unit root tests, or the cointegration test, or both.

I do not quite see a problem with one variable being seasonal, as long as you use a seasonally-adjusted version of that variable in the analysis.

Comment: I added an example of an output. So for I(1) variables that would be a contradictory result?

Comment: If I am reading the output correctly, it fits into what I have already written in the answer. On the one hand, you have that individually each variable is I(1). On the other hand, taken together the variables have more than one linear combination that is I(0), which suggest they are not individually I(1).

Comment: Also, do you have a reference for what you are saying? Where can I see a demonstration that a cointegration test between two variables I(1) in which we test away only one cointegrating vector and the resulting conclusion is that this actually contradicts their I(1) condition?

Comment: No, I do not have a reference. Such results are typically not publishable and you are supposed to find the root of the problem before proceeding. In other words, you are supposed to somehow solve the contradiction.