# Cointegration testing and seasonality

Tags: multiple-regression, seasonality, cointegration

I run the multiple regression on the monthly data. To remove the linear trends I subtracted it using detrend function in R (differencing data was not an option because I wanted to check the relationship between the exact variables). I run the kpss test which didn't reject the null hypothesis that the variables are stationary. I understand that this test will not detect seasonality. And that's my problem, because there is a clear seasonal component of order 12 in one of the variables:

I decided to run a regression anyway:
I have 4 explanatory variables, including one auto-regressive component. 
It is like this: 
$Y_t = aY_{t-1} + bX_t + cZ_t +d A_t$

All of the variables were significant, R squared isn't that big (0.7), picked explanatory variables are intuitively reasonable in explaining Y. Residuals are white noise and normally distributed. Durbin Watson statistic is higher than R squared. But I am still worried that it is spurious regression because of this seasonality. I wanted to check for cointegration, which would solve my problem, however the seasonality is of the order of 12, therefore the variable is not I(1), so I can't use Johansen or bound test. Is there any test for cointegration for the variables of higher orders of integration?

P.S 11 dummies made the majority of the variable insignificant.

Comment: You may be interested in: 1) tests for seasonal stability, the [Canova and Hansen test statistic](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/07350015.1995.10524598) is the seasonal counterpart of the KPSS test, 2) seasonal cointegration tests, 3) [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152664/) linked on the right side of this page.